# Does Stack Exchange have a site for elementary English questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Does Stack Exchange have a site for elementary English questions, such as the usage of articles and the appropriate tense of a sentence?

If not, why doesn't it have one?

I think the site I mentioned could be a so-called *minor-league* of the existing ELU site, so that questions in the elementary question site could be promoted if the question is approved to be sufficiently complicated or deep to be an ELU question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), there you can ask elementary English questions.

Refer their [on topic page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) you can ask in ELL, if you have questions about:

- Word choice, usage, and meaning
- Grammar
- Dialect differences
- Spelling and punctuation
- Pronunciation and accents
- Other practical problems you encounter or face while learning English

Comment: Ok that's what I found. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/sites -  there you can find the list of all Stack Exchange sites.